Are Cookie lifetime limited by browser?
I need to store a cookie in browser for a long time.
I handle the request with PHP, but I don't think it is very important the backend code because the response header looks like this:
Set-cookie:
mysession=qtxzgsqp1tmurif10nw2cb3rc1f340c6%7E1%7ER2; path=/; expires=Fri, 01-Dec-2034 18:17:28 UTC

Just after using my browser development tool, I query the cookie stored and I get:

As you can see the expiration is 2026 instead of 2034. Is there any fixed limit made by the browser?
I faced the same limit for Chrome and Firefox.

Consider carefully the purpose of a long-lived cookie. Ten years is a long time. A user may clear cookies at any time, may switch to a different browser, or may change their computer. Do you really think that cookie could still be there in ten years?
